# How do I deploy Thingspeak sever on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I tried to deploy Thingspeak on Heroku, I met with some errors below.

```
== 20101111054358 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
— create_table(:users)
-> 0.0111s
== 20101111054358 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0124s) =============================
== 20101116224140 CreateApiKeys: migrating ====================================
— create_table(:api_keys)
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column “write_flag” is of type boolean but default expression is of type integer
HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
: CREATE TABLE “api_keys” (“id” serial primary key, “api_key” character varying(16), “device_id” integer, “feed_id” integer, “user_id” integer, “write_flag” boolean DEFAULT 0, “public_flag” boolean DEFAULT 0, “created_at” timestamp, “updated_at” timestamp)
rake aborted!
```

---

```
class CreateApiKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :api_keys do |t|
      t.string :api_key, :limit => 16
      t.integer :device_id
      t.integer :feed_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.boolean :write_flag, :default => 0
      t.boolean :public_flag, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :api_keys
  end
end
```

I even solved this error by changing “0” to “false”, but another different error showed up on other table…

I can't figure out where it is wrong.

I downloaded thingspeak sever source code at http://angryelectron.com/how-to-install-a-thingspeak-server/

I am not a native speaker so I would try my best to express my question.

Comment: Did you write it as a string `default: "false"` or as an actual boolean `default: false`?

Comment: But I can deploy thingspeak on my local machine successfully with  mysql2 database.

Comment: , using the commamd of "rails s".